# What does heating Pd do in this organic reaction?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

[image]

I thought the answer to this question is 7 but the answer is 8. What happens in last step?

Answer (score 2):

After finding the intermediate products in the above process, the reactant in the final step comes out to be the following compound,

[image]

Now, the catalyst used in the final step was $\ce{Pd}$. According to this [abstract](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920586110001987),

> Supported gold, palladium and gold–palladium catalysts have been used to oxidatively dehydrogenate cyclohexane and cyclohexenes to their aromatic counterpart. The supported metal nanoparticles decreased the activation temperature of the dehydrogenation reaction. We found that the order of reactivity was Pd ≥ Au–Pd > Au supported on TiO2.

So, by this abstract it is clear that $\ce{Pd}$ catalyst is used for dehydrogenation of cyclohexenes. Accordingly the final step is given below,

[image]

---

**Usage of $\ce{Pd(II)}$ catalyst:** 
According to this [abstract](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja512770u),

> A palladium(II) catalyst system has been identified for aerobic dehydrogenation of substituted cyclohexenes to the corresponding arene derivatives.